blank page when try using useState in button with react

const Button = () =>{
    return (
            <button>My Button</button>
    )
}

export default Button

import React from 'react'
import './App.css'
import Button from "./components/button"
import Image from './components/image'
import { useState } from "react"

const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

const handlerClick = () => {
    setCount(count + 1)
}


const App = () =>{
  return (
    <>
      <Button count ={count} onClick ={handlerClick}/>
    </>
  )
}

export default App

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)


i starting to learn react and i try to made button with useState for adding number( i followed the react documentation, but i have create the button with components, import it into the app file, and import the app file into main.jsx for the root. Why my web page is still blank?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.


You can't use hooks like useState (or functions that update state) outside of a component. You should be getting some errors if you open your developer console log (F12).

While you're passing props to the button component the button component is not accepting any props.




const { useState } = React;

// Both the useState hook and the handler
// for updating state are INSIDE the component
function App() {

  const [ count, setCount ] = useState(0);

  function handleClick() {
    setCount(count + 1);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <Button
        count={count}
        handleClick={handleClick}
      />
    </div>
  );

}

// Accept the props into the Button component
// so that you can use them
function Button({ count, handleClick }) {
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={handleClick}
    >Clicked {count} times
    </button>
  );
}

const node = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(node);
root.render(<App />);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>



